# Capture stderr in ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python

Im using `ProcessPoolExecutor` to execute external command is there any way to capture **stderr** when the process is finished (similar to subprocess)? Im capturing `executor.submit()` future result but that returns 0 or 1.

Comment: This might help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.exception

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer but it is of that direction and far too long for a comment, so here goes.

I would say no to that. You *might* be able to achieve this by tinkering with stderr file descriptors, redirecting that to a stream of your own and returning this as the worker result but I am wondering if `ProcessPoolExecutor` is suitable for your task - of course not knowing what it is.

A subprocess created by a process pool does not finish like a subprocess created by yourself. It stays alive waiting for more work to arrive until you close the pool. If your worker produces stdout or stderr, they go to the same place where your main process directs its stdout and stderr.

Your workers will also process many different tasks. If your pool size is four and you submit ten tasks, how do you then decipher from a plain stderr capture which task created what message?

I have a hunch this needs to be redesigned. You would be able to raise exceptions in your workers and then later capture those from your future objects.  Or it might be that your task is something where a pool is just not suitable. If subprocesses do what you want them to do, why not use them instead?

Pools are good for parallelising repetitive tasks that return and receive modest amount of data (implemented as queues that are not miracle performers), with a standard interface and standardised output/error handling.  Pools simplify your code by providing the routine part. If your subtasks require different inputs, their outputs and error handling vary greatly or there is a lot of data to be transmitted, you might be better off by building the parallel processing part yourself.